# Converting a C function to Python function

Tags: python, arrays, function, python-3.x

this function searches the number of an element in an array and returns the number of the element in the array if it exists or returns -1 if the input number does not exist on the array

```
int iSearch (int st[],int len,int no)
{
    int i;
    for (i=1;i<=len;i++) //len=lenth of the array , no = the number that we want to search in the array , st[] = the array
      if (st[i]==no)
          return i;
      return -1;
}
```

and i want to write the python version of this function but since i use lists instead of arrays in python, i dont know how to write it in python.

i wrote the code below in python but it doesn't work

```
def iSearch(list,lenth,no):
    x=0
    for x in range (lenth):
        if (list(x) == no)
            return i
        else
            return -1
```

Comment: you don't need to have length !

Comment: which version of python you are using ?

Comment: im using python 3.6

Comment: `list.get(no, -1)` if you use correct types (here: `list` being a `dict`). Don't even consider porting C code 1:1 to Python. If you want to port code to a language you have to learn it first. And what is `i` in your code?

Comment: @Olaf That's not what the C function returns.

Comment: @DYZ: You are correct, but that's the problem with porting code 1:1 between such very different languages. This all smells like an XY problem. OP shows a too particular piece of code. The approach of writing C-style in Python will eventually result in increasingly unmanageable problems.

Comment: @Olaf The original function returns the _index_ of the element, but your code returns the _element_ by index. These are two orthogonal operations.

Comment: @DYZ: I already agreed you were right. Still this has the bad smell of XY problem, thus I provided an alternative view. I'n in fact very confident OP **needs** something very different than what he does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the loop equivalent:

```
def iSearch(lst,no):
  for i,x in enumerate(lst):
    if x == no:
      return i
  return -1
```

There is, however, function `lst.index(no)` which is doing what you need, but in a more efficient way:

```
def iSearch(lst,no):
  if no in lst:
    return lst.index(no)
  return -1
```

Or with the `try`/`except` (probably the fastest):

```
def iSearch(lst,no):
  try:
    return lst.index(no)
  except ValueError:
    return -1
```

Comment: `index` needs a `try/except` block BTW

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Correct.

Comment: gotcha: I had already upvoted :) and you don't have to feel bad about your probable downvoting of my crap answer. I don't take it personal, unlike the bozos who serial downvote you when you dupehammer a question.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you included the error you got next time.

Your code has some issues: 1. "list" is the name of an already existing object 2. You're only checking if the first item is the desired object, because at that point, both branches return. 3. accessing an element of a list requires square brackets, not parentheses.

This appears to work:

```
def linear_search_c(l,length,num):                                                                                                                    
  for x in range(0,length):                                                   
    if (l[x] == num):                                                       
        return x                                                            
  return -1
```

As an aside, there are better list searching methods than linear search if the array is sorted: [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

Comment: `x=0` is unnecessary here. and FYI for sorted arrays you can use `bisect` python module.

Comment: Thanks Fabre, good to know about bisect.